# Test if the difference of differences is significant

Tags: difference-in-difference

How to test if the difference between two groups is lower, higher or equal than the difference between two independent groups?

For example:
Is the height difference between a sample of male and female in Germany, higher than the height difference between a sample of male and female in Sweden?

Comment: Subtract male from female in both groups, compare the two differenced vectors with a test for comparing means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fit a linear model:
$$Y=\beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3 X_3 + \beta_4 X_4 +\epsilon$$
Where $X_1 = 1$ for Germany male, $X_2 = 1$ for Germany female, $X_3 = 1$ for Sweden male, $X_1 = 1$ for Sweden female, Otherwise, $X_i$ = 0.

Then test the null hypothesis 
$$\beta_1 - \beta_2 = \beta_3 - \beta_4$$ or $$\beta_1 - \beta_2 - \beta_3 + \beta_4 = 0$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Following user158565 advice, in r it should be something like:

```
#groups
f_g=rnorm(n = 49,mean = 165)
m_g=rnorm(n = 51,mean = 175)
f_s=rnorm(n = 42,mean = 170)
m_s=rnorm(n = 54 ,mean = 185)
mat=data.frame(height=c(f_g,m_g,f_s,m_s),
               group_=c(rep('f_g',length(f_g)),
                        rep('m_g',length(m_g)),
                        rep('f_s',length(f_s)),
                        rep('m_s',length(m_s))))
# fit model
fit=lm(height~ 0 + group_ ,data = mat)
# test hypothesis
linearHypothesis(fit,"group_f_g - group_m_g = group_f_s - group_m_s")
```